# how to increase performance on Spark distinct() on multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Could you please suggest alternative way of implementing distinct in spark data frame.

I tried both SQL and spark distinct but since the dataset size (>2 Billion) it fails on the shuffle .

If I increase the node and memory to >250GB, process run for a longe time (more than 7 hours).

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(out)
  
  val df1 = df.
   select($"ID", $"col2", $"suffix",
     $"date", $"year", $"codes").distinct()
   
   val df2 = df1.withColumn("codes", expr("transform(codes, (c,s) -> (d,s) )"))

   df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

   val df3 = spark.sql(
     """SELECT
           ID, col2, suffix
           d.s as seq,
           d.c as code,
           year,date
           FROM
            df2
             LATERAL VIEW explode(codes) exploded_table as d
             """)

   df3.
     repartition(
       600,
       List(col("year"), col("date")): _*).
     write.
     mode("overwrite").
     partitionBy("year", "date").
     save(OutDir)
```

Comment: can you post full code how are you reading or creating data frame ?? have you tried to increase number of partitions ??

Comment: what is the format of your data source?

Comment: To tackle this issue you can do a quick fix as before using the df just repartition it on all the used columns. This will provide you the advantage of data co-grouping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

Comment: Its a direct pull from parquet format ,  \ import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

  val df = spark.read.parquet(out)
  
  val df1 = df.
   select($"ID", $"col2", $"suffix",
     $"date", $"year", $"codes").distinct()

Comment: Source format - Parquet ( Having around 100 columns)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply - I have posted the full code

Comment: can u partition your data on year or is it already partitioned? and is ID  a unique value that can be used to check for distinct data ?

Comment: Hi Andy - year partition already exists and ID is not unique as per this dataset.